# Is there a way to fake a Touch into the system?

Tags: iphone, uitouch, multi-touch

I discovered this: When a UIView's touchesBegan: method is fired and there is only one finger on the screen, the system will wait up to 0.25 seconds to see if the finger move far enough, before it will fire touchesMoved:. There is no programmatically way to get around this problem.

But now the interesting part: If one finger is already somewhere on the screen, this ugly behavior is turned off. every next finger is interpteted as one that wants to move. touchesMoved: is fired immediately with no delay.

So the BIG question, guys: Is it possible to fake this first initial finger somewhere on the screen, so that the following real finger will be interpreted as a second finger? That would rescue my weekend ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matt Gallagher describes how to synthesize touch events in his post [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/synthesizing-touch-event-on-iphone.html).  He intends this more for user interface testing, though, because he does use some private instance variables which you would not want to rely on for a shipping application.